# What is wrong with the lines? (php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I get these error from nowhere... What is wrong?

> Warning: Division by zero in
>   /home/*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/*/includes/classes/controller/SearchPageController.php
>   on line 60
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/vineanimals/public_html/wp-content/plugins/*/includes/classes/controller/ImportPageController.php
>   on line 70
>
> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in
>   /home/*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/*/includes/classes/controller/AImportPageController.php
>   on line 75

line codes:

line 60:   `$last = ceil($load_products_result['total'] / $load_products_result['per_page']);`

line 70-75:

```
foreach ($product['sku_products']['variations'] as $var) {
                    if (isset($var['image'])) {
                        $product['all_images'][] = $var['image'];
                    }
                }
                $product['all_images'] = array_merge($product['all_images'], $this->woocommerce_model->get_images_from_description($product['description']));
            }
```

Comment: As the error is very clear, you have a division by 0 issue in your code.

Comment: Troubleshooting 101: Inspect all those variables and you'll realize load_prdoucts_result['per_page'] is set to 0. Chuck Norris is the only one that can divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

A) Check your SQL query or Array feed

B) Then change

```
 $last = ceil($load_products_result['total'] / $load_products_result['per_page']);
```

to:

```
$last = ( isset($load_products_result['per_page']) ? ceil($load_products_result['total'] / $load_products_result['per_page']) : 0)
```

C) and change the foreach as below:

```
if (is_array($product['sku_products']['variations'])){
    foreach ($product['sku_products']['variations'] as $var) {
            if (isset($var['image'])) {
                $product['all_images'][] = $var['image'];
            }
        }
    if (isset($product['description']) && is_array($product['all_images']) && is_array($this->woocommerce_model->get_images_from_description($product['description'])) )
    $product['all_images'] = array_merge($product['all_images'], $this->woocommerce_model->get_images_from_description($product['description']));
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean that

Comment: Try C) again, I have updated the code, your original code had an extra ending bracket `}` that was not necessary and also there was missing parenthesis for is_array()

Comment: Would appreciate if you vote for it and mark it as "Answer"